# How to resize DIV page to fit screen width?

Tags: html, resize

I found a simple web site design example using DIVs at the following link:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/img/3_column.html

The problem with this design is that it is a fixed width. I need a design where the wrapper DIV expands to the full screen area (100% width) and the header, main and footer DIVs resize along with it.

If I set the wrapper and footer widths to 100% it does take up the full area on a maximized browser window but shortening the window causes the right and main DIVs to wrap downwards. How can this wrapping be prevented?

Comment: So you don't want your wrapper to be 100%? because 100% means it re sizes with your browser. If you want a static width just enter 1280, 1024 or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you are looking for but surly using `float:right` or `float:left` on the div that is wraping under another div should fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into using [fluid960gs](http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/)

Answer (score 0):

Cant be done, only one attribute for DIV, which is the align attribute. Maybe consider using tables: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp
Shadowpat